Cardinality of localization of module over a non-commutative ring
Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring with unit, $S\subset R$ be a multiplicative subset containing $1$ satisfying left Ore condition:

For any $r_1,r_2\in R$ and $s\in S$ such that $r_1s=r_2s$, there exists $s'\in S$ such that $s'r_1=s'r_2$.
For any $r\in R$ and $s\in S$, there exists $r'\in R$ and $s'\in S$ such that $s'r=r's$.

Let $X$ be a left $R$-module, then one can define the localization $S^{-1}X$ consists of elements $s^{-1}x$ for $s\in S$ and $x\in X$, such that $s^{-1}x=(s')^{-1}x'$ if and only if there exists $u\in S$ and $v\in R$ such that $ux'=vx$ and $us'=vs$.
My question is: does $\#S^{-1}X\leq\#X$ hold in general?

When $\#S$ or $\#X$ is finite, it's easy to show that the natural map $X\to S^{-1}X$ is surjective.
In fact, if $\#S$ (resp. $\#X$) is finite, then for any $s\in S$ and $x\in X$ there exists $i>j$ such that $s^i=s^j$ (resp. $s^ix=s^jx$), and $s^{-1}x\in S^{-1}X$ is the image of $s^{i-j-1}x\in X$ (taking $u=s^j$ and $v=s^{j+1}$).

When $\#S$ and $\#X$ are infinite, $\#S^{-1}X\leq\#S\cdot\#X=\max(\#S,\#X)$.

if $S$ is commutative, then I can prove that $\#\{s^{-1}x\mid s\in S\}\leq\#X$ for each $x\in X$, because in this case, if $sx=s'x$ and $s,s'$ commutes, then $s^{-1}x=(s')^{-1}x$. Hence $\#S^{-1}X\leq\#X\cdot\#X=\#X$.

I have no idea when $S$ is not commutative. Any suggestions?





I don’t know why you’re interested in their cardinalies, but isn’t the cardinality of $S^{-1}R$ bounded by the cardinality of $R$ since the localisation is a quotient of $S\times R$ and $S$ is a subset?

Why should $X \to S^{-1} X$ be surjective?

@MPos you're right, but if $X$ is only an $R$-module, then I can only get $#S^{-1}X\leq\max(#S,#X)$ in general, because it's possible that $#R$ is uncountable but $#X$ is countable.

@MartinBrandenburg it's not true in general, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is not surjective; I mean that in some cases it's true.

Sure. I was referring to your finite case.

@MartinBrandenburg Post updated; proof included.

Ah, I see your point!
